# Execute SQL Stored procedure using Object_ID

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Is there any way to accomplish this?  For example, let's say the object_id for stored procedure X is 1234.  I'm trying to do something like

```
EXEC ('EXEC Object_Name(1234)')
```

and it would run stored procedure X.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you work with Oracle db.
To run procedure with known object_id you can use dictionary view `all_objects` and construct a call.
Here is an example:

```
declare
  iObjectId number := 3927531;
  sProcedureName varchar2(128);
  sProcedureOwner varchar2(128);
begin
  -- get the procedure name
  for c in (
    select object_name procedure_name,
           owner procedure_owner
    from   all_objects 
    where  object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
    and    object_id = iObjectId
  ) loop
    sProcedureName := c.procedure_name;
    sProcedureOwner := c.procedure_owner;
  end loop;

  if sProcedureName is not null then
    execute immediate 'begin '||sProcedureOwner||'.'||sProcedureName||'; end;';
    dbms_output.put_line('Procedure '||sProcedureName||' was executed successfully.');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Procedure was not found for object_id = '||iObjectId||'.');
  end if;

end;
```

Keep in mind that procedure can have required parameters. In this case you can use the dictionary view `all_arguments`.

Hope that helps.